# Making StructureMap configurable

Tags: c#, structuremap

StructureMap, starting from version 3.0, dropped the support of XML configuration. That is, I can no longer tell StructureMap which class satisfies which interface from the configuration. Instead, I have to mention that in the code itself. This limits my ability to be able to configure the code *without recompiling* the code.

Is there a way to make it configurable *without the need of recompiling* the solution? [Unity supports that natively](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660914(v=pandp.20).aspx).

If there is no way to do that, why did StructureMap removed that good feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML configuration is considered to be antiquated and support will no doubt eventually be removed from all DI containers. The fact of the matter is, strong typing by configuration in code is much easier to maintain than fragile XML structure and type strings.

If you need to change things around a bit without recompiling, you can always use `.config` files to add conditional behavior to the configuration (in the application's [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/)).

```
var option = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mySetting"];

if ("option1".Equals(option))
{
    container.For<ISomething>().Use<Something>();
}
else if ("option2".Equals(option))
{
    container.For<ISomething>().Use<SomethingElse>();
}
else
{
    container.For<ISomething>().Use<DefaultSomething>();
}
```

So you can still change things around, but without the fragile hard to maintain XML configuration that you won't realize fails until runtime.